# Parse fails to eval text

Tags: r

I have a variable which holds the names of multiple columns I want to create

```
> a_cols
[1] "a_100"  "a_500"  "a_2000" "a_200"
```

In addition to these, I also need the cols -> `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`. I want to create an empty table with these cols.

So I create an expression like this

```
expr <-  paste0(a_cols, " = 0", collapse=',')
expr <- paste("b = character(), c = character(), e = character(), d = logical()", expr, sep=',')
```

This expr when printed is this -

```
> expr
[1] "b = character(), c = character(), e = character(), d = logical(),a_100 = 0,a_500 = 0,a_2000 = 0,a_200 = 0"
```

But on parsing it, I get this error.

```
> parse(text = expr)
Error in parse(text = expr) : <text>:1:28: unexpected ','
1: b = character(),
                               ^
```

What is the issue here?

Is there a better way to create this table.

Note: The `a_cols` can have different values and is passed in as an input. So hard coding the column names directly wont work.

Adding how the expr is used.

`data.table(eval(parse(text = expr)))`

Comment: The current answer advises not to use `parse` here. That statement is not strong enough. Absolutely never create code as text that you then `eval(parse())`. Code written that way is difficult to understand, slow, impossible to debug and often creates difficulties later on. There is always a better approach. You should probably forget that `parse` even exists for now.

Comment: Thanks for the code improvement tips. Can some one still tell me why the parse does not work here?

Comment: Because what you have does not parse to a valid R expression. Something like `b = character(), c = character()` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Commas are only allowed between arguments in function calls. There is no function call around the commas here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the above answer worked, I also solved this in a different way.

```
other_cols <- c('b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
Reduce(function(acc, c) acc[, (c) := character()], c(other_cols, a_cols), data.table())
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `parse` here. You can initialize a dataframe by using :

```
a_cols <- c("a_100",  "a_500" , "a_2000" ,"a_200")
another_cols <- c('b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(c(a_cols, another_cols)), 
           dimnames = list(NULL, c(a_cols, another_cols)), nrow = 0))
```

To assign multiple columns with the same class you can use `lapply`

```
df[a_cols] <- lapply(df[a_cols], as.numeric)
df[another_cols] <- lapply(df[another_cols], as.character)
```

Or to assign individual classes to columns you can do :

```
df$a_500 <- as.logical(df$a_500)
```

Comment: Creating an empty data.frame is usually a sign of a flawed over-all approach. There is rarely a good reason to do that.

Comment: I completely agree with that. If OP shares the bigger picture and why they want to do that perhaps we can have a better suggestion.

Comment: I have a table which might be empty. One of the columns in the table is a json. I convert this json into columns(`a_cols`) using the row values. In the case it is empty I still need the columns, but I dont have the row data. So I create an empty datatable with the columns I need. P.S. I need to set the type of the columns as I join with another table later on.

Comment: Is there a way to set the col types at the same time of initializing these cols?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you can change class of columns after creating the dataframe.